# How to save a list of PFObject in iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform, cocos2d-x

I am working on iOS with `Parse.com` service as my cloud.

My current task is trying to retrieve friend list from Facebook then save that list to parse cloud.

I can use the sample/tutorial with parse.com for `PFObject` to save a single `PFObject` but when I tried to save a list of my objects it didn't work.

So can you explain to my why and which is the solution in my case?

My code:

```
for (NSDictionary<FBGraphUser>* friend_ in friends) {
                                                NSLog(@"I have a friend named %@ with id %@", friend_.name, friend_.id);
                                                PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
                                                NSLog(@"Add ID");
                                                gameScore[@"id"] = friend_.id;
                                                NSLog(@"Name");
                                                gameScore[@"name"] = friend_.name;
                                                NSLog(@"Birthday");
                                                gameScore[@"birthday"] = friend_.birthday;
                                                [gameScore saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (!error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"Sample sending completed");
                                                    }
                                                }];

                                            }
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Are you receiving an error from Parse?

Comment: Just nothing. I tried to check on data browser as well but no data was sent to there

Comment: Is saveInBackgroundWithBlock returning success or an error?

Comment: Thanks Brandon, It even returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this issue too when saving multiple objects in Parse with multiple requests. You should try the following request, which allows you to save an array of PFObject * with a single request :

```
+ (void)saveAllInBackground:(NSArray *)objects block:(PFBooleanResultBlock)block
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the saveAllInBackground method?

Comment: saveAllInBackground is a class method (you can se it with the +(void) instead of -(void)), and its documentation is here : https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/saveAllInBackground:
-- Call it like this : [PFObject saveAllInBackground:@[object1,object2] block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){ /*completion code */ }];

Answer (score 0):

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore”];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore setObject:@"Sean Plott" forKey:@"playerName"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"cheatMode"];
[gameScore save];
```